# How to compute ringct multisignature key images? (Disambiguation of MRL005)

Tags: ringct, multisig, monero-research-lab, key-image, elliptic-curve

I'm looking at the multisignature scheme provided by [MRL005 Section 4.4](https://www.getmonero.org/resources/research-lab/pubs/MRL-0005.pdf#subsection.4.4), and some things are unclear to me. I've attached a picture below of the expression for which I'm seeking some clarification.

[image: Monero Multisignature Snippet]

Above, we have:

1. A generated key image (Ij)
2. A hash function (H)
3. A shared public key (Pe)
4. And a signer-specific public key (Pj)

No ambiguity there.

The actual operations required to calculate a given key image are the core of my questions.

**Question 1: For the term (Pe | Pj)**

- Am I correct to interpret this as an *inner product* of the shared, and signer-specific public keys?

**Question 2: For the term (Pe | Pj)**

- How would one actually calculate this value, given the two public keys?  A detailed example would be preferred here.

**Question 3: For the term H()**

- Which hash function is used here?  Sha512, as in EdDSA? Keccak? Or something else?

Comment: Keep in mind MRL0005 is out of date. You can find more current resources on multisig in MRL0009 and Zero to Monero 2 ch. 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 & 2 - `Pe | Pj` is concatenation of the keys.

3 - Keccak, although as @knaccc comments, `H()` is not simply a hash function, it's hash-to-point, so should read `Hp()`.

Comment: I think that there is a typo in MRL005, and that H() is actually Hp(). Otherwise the result of multiplication would not result in an EC point key image. I failed to figure out the nature of their entire multisig scheme from their brief description.

Comment: @knaccc indeed, it should read `Hp()` not `H()`. The MRL005 note (which is all it seems to be) is quite different to much of the multisig code.

Comment: This makes a lot more sense now. Thanks to you both. I don't have enough rep to upvote